# .pgp-ключи продолжают появляться в директории /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/

Tags: linux, apt, gpg, dpkg

Использую `Linux Mint 21 Vanessa`.

Установил себе с официальных сайтов пакеты `Google Chrome` и `Opera`.
При установке этих пакетов они автоматически устанавливают свои репозитории и ключи, причём ключи помещают в папку `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/`.
Таким образом у меня в этой папке образовались следующие ключи:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Потом я узнал, что ключи безопаснее хранить в директории `/etc/apt/keyrings/` и переместил их туда, попутно переименовав ключи оперы 2021 года в `opera-browser.gpg`.
Также я изменил строки в `sources.list.d` на такие:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема в том, что при обновлении этих программ они всё так же устанавливают старые ключи в `trusted.gpg.d`. Хорошо хоть, что строки источников не меняют.

Но это ещё понятно, и с этим можно мириться. Бо́льшая проблема в том, что даже при отключении этих репозиториев (как видно на картинке) эти ключи (все три) со временем появляются в папке `trusted.gpg.d`, причём я до сих пор не понял, в какой момент это происходит.

Мне совершенно непонятно, почему они там появляются. У кого-нибудь есть какие-то идеи?

---

Update: нашёл "постинстол" скрипты в папке `/var/lib/dpkg/info/`.
Называются `google-chrome-stable.postinst` и `opera-stable.postinst`.
Кто-нибудь знает, можно как-то сказать `dpkg`, чтобы он не вызывал эти конкретные скрипты? Можно, наверное, просто удалить их, но они наверняка установятся заново, да и не хочется удалять их, на самом деле, потому что в них могут быть записаны и другие важные функции.
Кажется, придётся всё-таки отказаться от `.deb` пакетов и перейти на `flatpak` и `snap`, которым я предпочитаю `apt`.(

---

Update: я удалил (полностью - `purge`) `Google Chrome` и `Opera`. Если вместе с ними шли пакеты по типу `...-keyring`, то тоже удалил. Никаких `.postinst`, связанных с хромом и оперой не осталось.

Ключ гугла больше не появляется, но ключи оперы продолжают появляться!

Я делал поиск по содержимому по всей системе, вводя свова `opera`, `packager@opera.com`, `4346`, `B7A0`, но ничего не нашёл.

Не понимаю, что заставляет ключи опять появляться.

---

Update: нашёл файл с названием `opera-browser` в директории `/etc/cron.daily`. Из-за этого-то файла ключи и появлялись.

Comment: В постинстал хуке , который выполняется при каждом обновлении системы скорее всего

Comment: @eri а можно по-русски?) Что мне с этим делать? Можно этот "хук" удалить?

Comment: `и переместил их туда` — напрасно. почему напрасно? да вот сам факт наличия этого вопроса как раз об этом и свидетельствует. храните **свои** ключи там, где считаете безопаснее, а внутрь всяких левых пакетов лучше не лезть. даже так: левыми пакетами лучше вообще не засорять свою систему.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin ну так я храню ключи там, где безопаснее - `/etc/apt/keyrings/`. И переместил я их туда не напрасно, потому что в `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/` их хранить небезопасно.

Comment: мне кажется, не имеет смысла переживать о такой мелочи, как место храниния ключей, после того, как вы сами же пробили в безопасности системы громадную дырень, установив (как минимум) два левых пакета с проприетарными блобами внутри. как говорится, «тушите свет»: безопасность системы уже провалена полностью.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin на самом деле нет, я ведь видел файлы пакетов перед установкой. Да и безопасность здесь с чисто философской стороны, поскольку гугл и опера в свои пакеты вирусы встраивать не будут, а взломать их могут с той же, если не меньшей, вероятностью, как и репозитории минта или убунты. А переживать насчёт хранения ключей всё-таки стоит.

Comment: А чем это безопаснее?

Comment: @eri тем, что apt полностью доверяет всем ключам, перечисленным в `trusted.gpg.d`, независимо от репозитория, который этот ключ "открывает" (хз, какой термин использовать). То есть кто-то, кто имеет приватный ключ гугла или оперы в моём случае может подменить пакет в любом другом репозитории в мире, и `apt` на моём компьютере с удовольствием его скачает. В то же время ключи, хранимые в `keyrings` указываются для каждой строки источника отдельно, таким образом каждый ключ "открывает" строго определённые репозитории.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, чтобы ключи `Google Chrome` не появлялись, я удалил `Google Chrome` (`'dev'`-версию). Возможно, можно написать свой скрипт, который вызывался бы после обновления системы и удалял эти ключи после установки `.deb`-пакета для хрома.

Однако в директории `/etc/cron.daily` остался файл `opera-browser` даже после удаления `.deb`-пакета `Opera`, который и обновлял ключи. После удаления этого файла ключи перестали появляться.